# ASP.NET MVC3 generating google maps through address

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, google-maps-api-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework and I want to use Google Maps (v3) to display the location of my customers. I can take the value of their addresses/City from the database, but how can I combine these two? I'm using Razor engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to Google Maps I would suggest reading through their [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html) and looking over the [examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) to get an idea on how the API works.

Another good tutorial to look at is the 4 guys from Rolla article on implementing a store locator application.  The article was originally written in [Web Forms](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201156/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051910-1.aspx) and then later [updated to MVC](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927193940/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081810-1.aspx).  There is relevant information in both.  They do not use Razor views, but they do a good job at showing how to query the Google Maps API on the server side and packaging the results in a JSON object to display on the map.

Your View will be pretty simple if you just want markers on a map.  The only HTML you would need is a div to store the map.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting your addresses through AJAX. MVC has a lot of good JSON stuff (like `JsonResult`), so you'll be able to send objects instead of parsing HTML. Since you're doing AJAX, I'm obliged to mention JQuery, I don't make AJAX calls without it. You can add the `HttpPost` attribute to your JSON response function too, and even make it secure!